# AngularJS data binding not working with External Controller file

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a simple code file on [CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YxdqWB?editors=1010)
I am trying to use `{{ }}` and `ng-bind=""` but neither one is working. Basically I have to display some data on `ng-init`.

Answer (score 1):

You are actually missing this,

```
  <div ng-app="myApp.controllers" ng-controller="Report as ctrl">
```

**DEMO**

```js
angular.module("myApp.controllers", []);

(function(angular) {
  "use strict";
  function Report($scope) {
    let ctrl = this;
    ctrl.reports = "Rolys Royc H87H";
    $scope.reportInfo = "Aircraft";

    ctrl.$onInit = function() {
      $scope.reportInfo = "Aircraft";
    };
  }
  Report.$inject = ["$scope"];

  angular.module("myApp.controllers").controller("Report", Report);
})(angular);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<html>

<head>
  <title>AngularJS Directives</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Sample Application</h1>
  <div ng-app="myApp.controllers" ng-controller="Report as ctrl">
    <h4 ng-bind="ctrl.reports"></h4>
    <h4 ng-bind="reportInfo"></h4>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This works. You had not specified either `ng-app` or `ng-controller`

<kbd>**Codepen Demo**</kbd>

Code:

```
<html>

<head>
  <title>AngularJS Directives</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Sample Application</h1>
  <div ng-app="myApp.controllers" ng-controller="Report as ctrl">

    <h4 ng-bind="ctrl.reports"></h4>
    <h4 ng-bind="reportInfo"></h4>
  </div>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="a.js"></script>
  <script src="abc.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```